# Why using __attribute__ (section) for some memory allocation?

Tags: attributes, linker-scripts, gcc4.9

I have `foo[NUMBYTES] __attribute__((section(".bar")));`

Why using this attribute .bar section? Because foo[] provides already some memory space. Is this for easy memory management?

Answer (score 1):

For *bare metal* code that run without an operating system, the section attribute ,`__attribute__((section(".bar")))`, is often used to:

- Place symbols (data or functions) in a special memory space, such as RAM, FLASH or EEPROMs built into microcontrollers.
- Place symbols at a special address, e.g. placing the interrupt vector table at the start of FLASH for ARM Cortex-M processors.
- Group related symbols continuously, e.g. the Linux kernel groups initialization code that is only needed at boot together (see `init section` in [linux/init.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/init.h?v=3.17#L59)) so it can free them later to save RAM.

Search your linker script for references to the named section (`.bar`) and you could probably make a good guess for its use.