# _attribute(section("NC_BSS")... what is the meaning of this?

Tags: c++, attributes

I am using a Renesas microcontroller, and I found this line in sample code

```
static uint8_t Video[SIZE]__attribute((section("NC_BSS"),aligned(32)));
```

I am wondering what this mean?

---

I am aware that the attribute section means (as it is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27679669/why-using-attribute-section-for-some-memory-allocation) that the array is being located in a particular section. But I have no idea what this NC_BSS section is... is there anyone here familiar with this or Renesas programming?

Also, a simple explanation of what the "aligned 32" would imply in this particular case will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The name .bss or bss is used by many compilers and linkers for a part of the data segment containing statically-allocated variables represented solely by zero-valued bits initially (i.e., when execution begins). It is often referred to as the "bss section" or "bss segment"*

The NC referrs to non-cacheable bss section.